# Create transaction serialization-lib > version 10

Tags: transaction, cardano-serialization-lib, javascript

I'm using cardano-serialization-lib `^9.1.2` to create transaction.

I'm using method that are now deprecated in version `10`, so is there an example of transaction with serialization-lib latest version used on nodejs?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the changelog here for some examples and explanations: https://github.com/Emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib/releases/tag/10.0.0

A rough example could look something like this:

```
function createExampleTx() {

  const protocolParams = await blockfrost.fetchParameters();
  
  // Create TransactionBuilderConfig (see func below)
  const txBuilderConfig = getTxBuilderConfig(protocolParams);

  // Create TransactionBuilder
  const txBuilder = TransactionBuilder.new(txBuilderConfig);

  txBuilder.set_ttl(protocolParams.slot + 10000);

  // Create and add outputs
  const txOut = TransactionOutputBuilder.new()
    .with_address(RECEIVER)
    .next()
    .with_coin(BigNum.from_str("5000000"))
    .build();

  txBuilder.add_output(txOut);

  // Create and add Inputs
  const utxos = await getUtxos(SENDER);
  txBuilder.add_inputs_from(utxos, CoinSelectionStrategyCIP2.LargestFirst);

  // Add change and fees
  txBuilder.add_change_if_needed(SENDER);

  // Build transaction
  const txBody = txBuilder.build();

  const unsignedTx = Transaction.new(
    txBody,
    TransactionWitnessSet.new()
  );

  // ...
}

function getTxBuilderConfig(protocolParams: ProtocolParameters): TransactionBuilderConfig {

  return TransactionBuilderConfigBuilder.new()
    .fee_algo(LinearFee.new(
      BigNum.from_str(protocolParams.linearFee.minFeeA),
      BigNum.from_str(protocolParams.linearFee.minFeeB)
    ))
    .pool_deposit(BigNum.from_str(protocolParams.poolDeposit))
    .key_deposit(BigNum.from_str(protocolParams.keyDeposit))
    .max_tx_size(protocolParams.maxTxSize)
    .max_value_size(parseInt(protocolParams.maxValSize!))
    .coins_per_utxo_word(BigNum.from_str(protocolParams.coinsPerUtxoWord!))
    .build()

}
```